# docker run only displays last CMD?

Tags: docker

I create a docker image with two echos but only the last one is displayed:

*dockerfile*:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

CMD echo "HELLO WORLD"
CMD echo "GOODBYE WORLD"
```

*build and run*:

```
docker build -t junk:junk .
docker run -it junk:junk
```

The output is

```
GOODBYE WORLD
```

How can I control the output of `docker run -it`?

Comment: You can only have a single `CMD` in your `Dockerfile`. If you have more than one, only the last one matters. If you want to run more than a single command, put them in a script and arrange for the `CMD` to run the script.

Comment: @larsks if you write an answer i'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Docker image can only have a single `CMD`. If you have multiple `CMD` declarations in your `Dockerfile`, only the last one will matter. If you want to run multiple commands, you can combine them into a single `CMD`, like this:

```
CMD echo HELLO WORLD; echo GOODBYE WORLD
```

Or you can put them into a script file and then have your `CMD` run the script:

```
COPY myscript.sh /myscript.sh
CMD sh /myscript.sh
```